# How to access a parameter of one resolver in another?

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

This is the code snippet I wish the access the instanceName Property in class Product

```
class Product(graphene.ObjectType):
    productName=graphene.String()
    productDependecies=graphene.List(ProductDependency)
   '''
                     I wish to access the instanceName here in this class How Can I do it 
   '''
  class Instance(graphene.ObjectType):
    instanceName=graphene.String()
    products=graphene.List(Product)
    def resolve_products(self,info):
       #some code that follows
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `resolve_products` method, when you instantiate the list of `Product` instances, you can pass the instance name into each `Product`.

```
class Product(graphene.ObjectType):
    instance_name = graphene.String()
    ...

class Instance(graphene.ObjectType):
    instance_name = graphene.String()
    ...
    def resolve_products(self, info):
        # return list of Product objects here, where
        # product = Product(instance_name=self.instance_name ...)
```

It's recommended that you snake-case your values and let graphene convert to camel case for you, and in my example I am using snake case.

This isn't the only solution, but it should be straightforward.